# How to resolve the following Firebase realtime database error?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[screenGrab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebBet.png)

how can that specific error be resolved ?

Tried adding null aware operators. Expected to handle firebase realtime updates.
Looking to work around having to use the [] method while retaining original intentions of code which is to handle changes in a firebase real time database.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.

You have to cast the type Object as Map, i.e.

```
var data = event.snapshot.value as Map;
if(data.keys.contains("car_details"){
  setState(() {
    carDetailsDriver = data["car_details"];
  )}
}
```